# Java memory going up hence application behaving abnormally

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, operating-system, jvisualvm

My java memory is going up by 500 MB and making my application behave abnormally like having some UI glitches.

Can anyone tell me how to analyze why the java memory is going up?

I have already tried jvisualvm but there only java thread classes are showing up nothing specific to my application.

I cross-checked all the logs, no exception is present.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: I don't know about your application or your environment - but it sounds like you should probably familiarize yourself with [VisualVM](https://dzone.com/articles/all-about-visualvm): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr025.html

Comment: I have already tried jvisualvm , but no luck. @paulsm4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jvisualvm to analyze memory usage. Connect to your process and select the Sampler tab. Then sample the Memory.
I highlighted the buttons in this [screenshot of the jvisualvm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gFaQ.png)
In the table you can now see how much memory is taken for different objects by the java application. It may not seem helpful to see that most memory ist taken by char[], but you can sort by Class Name an find your own packages and classes.
You can take Snapshots, do some action in your App, take another Snapshot and compare. This may lead you to a memory leak.

I don't know much about your application, but 500 MB may be OK. Perhaps you want to look into the logs or enable them. When you have abnormal behaviour your app or your libraries might log error messages that help correcting the wrong behaviour.